# Aurelia: Nested template replace

Tags: templates, aurelia

Is there a way to replace part of a replaced template? I expect the final table in  [this](https://gist.run/?id=a52a0c17d0f7bae22b9ea1987ddc5583) example to resolve as top: "whatever here" but it resolves as the previous template. Is this not allowed in Aurelia or am I missing something?

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="./baseGrid"></require>
  <require from="./grid"></require>

  <base-grid></base-grid>
  --------------------------------------------
  <grid></grid>
  --------------------------------------------
  <grid>
    <template replace-part="entry">
      top: ${datum}
    </template>
  </grid>
  --------------------------------------------
</template>
```

baseGrid.html

```
<template>
  <template replaceable part="table">
    <table>
      <tr repeat.for="datum of data">
        <td>${datum}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </template>
</template>
```

baseGrid.js

```
export class BaseGrid {
  data = 'This is the base grid'.split(' ');
}
```

grid.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./baseGrid"></require>
  <base-grid>
    <template replace-part="table">
      <table>
        <tr repeat.for="datum of data">
          <td>
            <template replaceable part="entry">
              grid: ${datum}
            </template>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </template>
  </base-grid>
</template>
```

grid.js

```
export class Grid { }
```

[Here](https://gist.run/?id=bf6949bb5ca3afd6f54cee7f1ae3bad4) is a similar implementation but trying to replace child templates.

Comment: Upon a cursory look, wouldn't using slots help here? http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection/1

Comment: @JeffG, slots won't work on repeated elements, because then you would have duplicate slot names which breaks.

Comment: Apparently Aurelia does not want to support template inheritance but there might be a way to get the same functionality using other methods. I'm going to take a look at the suggestions made [here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/451) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/463)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Aurelia does not support this but [enhancement](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/493) #493 has been requested to bridge this gap.